# Xamarin.Forms Picker`s ItemDisplayBinding doesn't change displayed text when property on object changes

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I have a xaml code:

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding profiles}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding name}" SelectedItem="{Binding selectedProfile}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0, 0, 20, 0" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

In cs file I defined:

```
BindingContext = this;
```

and

```
    private ObservableCollection<Profile> _profiles = new ObservableCollection<Profile>();
    public ObservableCollection<Profile> profiles
    {
        get { return _profiles; }
        set { _profiles = value; }
    }
```

And profile class is:

```
public class Profile
{
    private string _name = "New profile";
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

It works properly when I add/remove elements, and select new one in dropdown list or code (selectedProfile = profiles[index]).
But the problem occurs when I trying to rename profile. I changed profile name, but Picker didn`t update it and I see the old value.

I also tried this. But now result.

```
public class Profile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name = "New profile";
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }        
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for your Profile class

Comment: Gerald, I have updated post, it doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to update a information inside a item on a list. Here is my answer to how you can do it:

[How to update informations inside a item on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144583/update-list-view-on-expand/49253924#49253924)

You will probably adapt for your need, but I guess that it will help to guide you.

Answer (score 0):

**`'ItemDisplayBinding'`** isn't bindable property, that's why I think u can't notify it.
You will have to **create a custom picker.**

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem several times.

Here is a light solution to update a picker linked to a source of type `ObservableCollection<T>`:

```
var l_nIndex = Items.IndexOf(SelectedItem);

Items.Move(l_nIndex, l_nIndex);

RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
```

`Items` property is a collection of `Item` it is an `ObservableCollection<Item>`

`SelectedItem` is the binded property that represents the selected `Item` in the picker

Here is the xaml code that creates the picker in the view :

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```